# Eclipse Luna Workspace not working

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace

My instructor has provided me with a lab to work on. I just downloaded the file and opened eclipse, then switched the workspace to that folder but the files are not loaded. Thats the window that appears:

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=34oalhx&s=8

Comment: Try 'File > Refresh'.

Comment: Refresh is not enabled

Comment: Go to `File -> Import`. Then select `Existing Projects into Workspace` and choose the folder.  Then check the projects you want to import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work on a previously created project in Eclipse you need to `Import` it.

You can follow the instructions detailed [here](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/import_export/).

Comment: i didnt create it, my instructor provided it to me.

Comment: Doesn't matter who created the project, the steps to access it in your Eclipse workspace are the same.